# How do I install ServiceStack.Interfaces?

Tags: asp.net, nuget, nuget-package

I have tried installing the [ServiceStack Framework](https://github.com/ServiceStack) on both .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5 applications. I have gotten the same error both times:

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces 4.0.31'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any 
assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Servicestack
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

**and**

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces 4.0.31'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any 
assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Servicestack
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

What gives?

Comment: `ServiceStack.Interfaces` is now a [portable library as of v4.0.30](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release-notes.md#improved-pcl-story). Odd, I've tested on both v4 and v4.5 ASP.NET Web and Console App projects and it references the pcl `ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll` both times. You could try a clean install by uninstalling and re-installing the NuGet packages. How are you creating the project?

Comment: What version of NuGet do you have installed? PCL support was added in NuGet 2.1

Comment: @mythz I created the project using the wizard. `New Project->Set Target Framework=>C#/ASP.Net MVC 4->Empty`. Then I tried installing  the `ServiceStack webservice framework` using both the wizard and the Package Manager Console. Does that help?

Comment: It helps being able to test how you've created the project but this still works for me, maybe you need to [upgrade NuGet](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget)?

Comment: @mythz That was totally the issue. Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major change to happen to `ServiceStack.Interfaces` is that it's now a [portable library as of v4.0.30](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release-notes.md#improved-pcl-story) supporting most supported platforms (Profile136):

- .NET 4.0+
- Xamarin.iOS
- Xamarin.Android
- Windows Store
- Silverlight 5

If NuGet is reporting that it can't find the necessary assembly references for a supported platform than it's likely that you're using an older version of NuGet that doesn't include PCL support, which can be resolved by [upgrading to the latest NuGet](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget).

Answer (score 1):

The "upgrade Nuget" option was not working for me.  Turns out that versions of ServiceStack do have .NET limits.  Our application is .NET 4.0, so ServiceStack.Interfaces 4.062 was the highest version we could install.